# Heap memory chart in Dynatrace

Tags: heap-memory, dynatrace

I did the load testing in staging environment and I need to check heap memory usages in dashlets. Currently I am using Dynatrace 7.0 client.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Dynatrace AppMon can record memory per PurePath or for the complete heap. In your case you are likely looking for a complete heap memory snapshot/analysis.

For this I suggest you take a look at the documentation at [memory analysis](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/application-monitoring-tutorials/memory-analysis/) and [memory diagnostics](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/runtime-diagnostics/memory-diagnostics/) in the documentation.

The memory dashlet is described in more detail at https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/appmon-client/dashlets/total-memory-dashlet/, basically you just need to open the memory dashlet and trigger a memory dump via "Create Memory Snapshot" and select the agent for the process that you would like to analyze.

Results are displayed in a separate dashlet, see https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/appmon-client/dashlets/total-memory-dashlet/total-memory-content-dashlet/ for documentation.